# Why the first view in my project is not taken the name of the project

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

When i create new project with the name `MyNewProject` with a single view application template, with the storyboard feature, i got the view controller named `ViewController`. My Question is why i am not getting a view named `MyNewProjectViewController`? am i always obliged to rename the view manually? is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the project, you can tell Xcode to add a **Class Prefix** to the generated class files. You can set it to `MyNewProject` if you want and your view controller will be called 
`MyNewProjectViewController`.

[image]

However, the class prefix is generally much shorter than that (two or three letters). For example, for a project called **Anrgy Birds**, I would use the prefix **AB**.